# CREATE FUNCTION ERROR IN MYSQL

Tags: mysql, function, mysql-error-1064

I'm having this error:
***Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 19***

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION cadastrar_usuario(email VARCHAR(100), senha VARCHAR(30), nome VARCHAR(100), sobrenome VARCHAR(100)) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE ID INT;
DECLARE EXISTE_EMAIL INT;

IF (email = '') || (senha = '') || (nome = '') || (sobrenome = '') THEN
    RETURN 1;

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO ID;

SELECT COUNT(CODUSUARIO) FROM USUARIO_EMAIL WHERE EMAIL = email INTO EXISTE_EMAIL;
IF EXISTE_EMAIL > 0 THEN
    RETURN 2;

INSERT INTO USUARIO VALUES(0, senha, nome, sobrenome);
INSERT INTO USUARIO_EMAIL VALUES(ID, email, NULL);

RETURN 0;
  **END$$** This is the line 19

    DELIMITER ;
```

I Have no idea, what is the problem.

Thanks already.

Comment: Try END $$ with space.

Comment: Didn't work, and the same error.

Comment: You forgot the END IFs.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close your `IF` blocks:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS cadastrar_usuario;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION cadastrar_usuario(email VARCHAR(100), senha VARCHAR(30), 
    nome VARCHAR(100), sobrenome VARCHAR(100)) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
DECLARE ID INT;
DECLARE EXISTE_EMAIL INT;

IF (email = '') || (senha = '') || (nome = '') || (sobrenome = '') THEN
    RETURN 1;
END IF;

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO ID;

SELECT COUNT(CODUSUARIO) FROM USUARIO_EMAIL WHERE EMAIL = email INTO EXISTE_EMAIL;

IF EXISTE_EMAIL > 0 THEN
    RETURN 2;
END IF;

INSERT INTO USUARIO VALUES(0, senha, nome, sobrenome);
INSERT INTO USUARIO_EMAIL VALUES(ID, email, NULL);

RETURN 0;

END

$$

DELIMITER ;
```

( Tested and working on MySQL 5.6.12-community ).

Comment: You ought to mark the answer as approved, then (while upvoting is not required).